# What is an easy to cover the gap between tap and garden system

Tags: pipe

I changed the multi tap adapted and the new one doesn't give enough length to attach to the watering system.

[image]

How can I bridge the gap between the tap and the watering system. What pieces would I need?

Comment: I mean, I'd just stick a short stub of hose between the tap and the manifold.

Comment: Why have a 4 tap manifold if you only have one line?  The green quick connect fittings on the manifold look to be compatible with the hose bib .  Just get a short hose and attach it to the tap and screw the quick connect to the other end.  Plug the male and female quick connects together...done.

Comment: @RMDman there are two lines plus a hose, It was simpler to just show one when taking the photo. They don't stand up on their own

Answer (score 1):

An in-line hose-thread pressure regulator or filter between the spigot and the manifold would drop the manifold down several inches.

[image: Pressure regulator]

*Image source https://stc.dripdepot.com/400x400/1705/senninger-three-quarter-inch-hose-thread-pressure-regulator-10341.jpg no endorsement implied*

[image: In-line filter] [image: Inline filter parts]

*Image source https://stc.dripdepot.com/300x300/1457/inline-hose-filter-by-global-84246.jpg and https://stc.dripdepot.com/300x300/1457/inline-hose-filter-by-global-48612.jpg no endorsement implied*